# ¿Cómo actualizar los metadatos de forma dinamica en angular?

Tags: angularjs, meta-tags

contexto: tengo una spa en angular y en ella estoy mostrando las entradas de un blog, lo que se quiere es que cuando la  persona comparta en redes sociales el links aparezca su respectivo titúlo con imagen me aconsejaron integrar angular universal tod muy bien y en mi componente tengo este codigo para actualizar los metadatos me funciona en la consola del navegador pero no en el codigo fuente entonces a la hora de compartir el link no aparece nada

con este codigo actualizo los metadatos pero no funciona

```
        const metaTags: any[] =[
            { name: 'description', content: this.posts.description },
            { property: 'og:title', content: this.posts.title },
            { property: 'og:title', content: this.posts.description },
            { property: 'og:image', content: this.posts.img }
        ]
        // Actualiza las metaetiquetas
        this.meta.addTags(metaTags);
```